# React Native- Unexpected Token o in JSON at position 1 / Asyncstorage

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm lost, i have been trying so many things, I don't understand why I get this error when I'm trying to read from asyncstorage react native, I understand that for me to get asyncstorage as a string I need to convert it using something like parse but I'm getting stuck in this kinda of error.

```
    class AddScreen extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        i=0;
        super(props);
        var text = {};
        this.state = {text: ''};
      }

      setName = (text) => {
        text.name = text;
        //  alert(t)
        var name = ("name"+i++);
        //    alert(name);
        AsyncStorage.setItem(name, text);

        this.setState({ name: text });
        var booga=  AsyncStorage.getItem(name);
        // var stringified = JSON.stringify(booga.name);
        var booga1 = JSON.parse(booga);
        alert(booga1);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>

          <TextInput
          style={{height: 100}}
          placeholder="Name of expense"
          onChangeText={this.setName}

          />
          <View style={{width: 50, height: 100}} />
          <Text>Add  Screen</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }


    }
```

This is the error I get when I run my app on my device using expo

```
    Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    Object.AddScreen._this.setName [as onChangeText]
        App.js:26:20
    Object._onChange
        TextInput.js:1252:42
    Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:9
    invokeGuardedCallback
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:30
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:342:24
    executeDispatch
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:715:2
    executeDispatchesInOrder
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:737:4
    executeDispatchesAndRelease
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:894:4
    executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel
        ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:902:9
```

Comment: I suspect you are not awaiting the asynchronous call to your storage and possibly trying to parse the returned promise. 

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

Why are you call the async storage function for each change in the characters? 
It is not a proper way. Please read the async storage on `componentDidMound()` function. And write to async storage on button click or something else.

```
//method to read from async storage
readData() {
   AsyncStorage.getItem("LOGED_CREDENTIALS").then(value => {
      if (value) {
        let data = JSON.parse(value);
        // your code here...
      } else {
        //if error...
      }
   });
}

//write data
setData(data){
  AsyncStorage.setItem(
     "LOGED_CREDENTIALS",
     JSON.stringify(data)
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a function to read from text input and send it to asyncstorage. I was just testing to make sure I know how to use different parts of what I need to do.